# What does "additional tuition" mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Does it mean "The tuition" or "the interest of the tuition"? (For example, the tuition is 50,000 USD, and after 1 year unpaid by graduates, it may become 60,000 USD.)

"Students who enroll in the San Francisco or New York campus can defer payment until after graduation. In return, the school can collect a share of your first-year salary once you earn $50,000 in total compensation. No additional tuition is charged if you don’t find a job within one year of graduating."

Source: https://www.cnbc.com/2018/12/21/6-schools-that-dont-require-tuition-until-you-get-a-job.html

Comment: You would have to ask them.

Comment: As explanations go, that one is rather unclear. It would be highly unusual for a debt to have zero percent interest. I understand the passage to mean that once you have found a job that will pay $50,000 in total annual gross compensation (presumably including benefits), the school can begin to collect a share of your total compensation and it may continue to do so in subsequent years until your tuition (and any accrued interest) is paid off. The school may have a provision that deals with cases of intermittent unemployment and variations in compensation from year to year.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo The school is saying that if they can't get you a job, they won't charge you the additional part (not really interest). It's a boot camp, so what is "usual" doesn't really apply.

Comment: @Accumulation:  I would read the fine print.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't consider "interest" to be quite the right word. The wording definitely says that the extra money isn't owed if you don't get a job. It implies, but does not say, that the base tuition is owed even if you don't get a job.

Answer (score 0):

They have several plans, which are linked from the CNBC article you quoted.  I think the confusing word here is "defer", which implies that that tuition is charged at the start and only payment is delayed (like a loan).  In fact, there are several plans, and in the ones where you pay less initially, you only owe more ("additional tuition") if you get a job within one year meeting certain requirements.